# WPF Entityframework. Binding вычисляемого свойства

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, binding

Добрый день. Не могу забиндить свойство сущности в столбец датагрида.
Сущность Student со свойствами Price  и LessonLength портирована из БД (DataBase First). Создал свое свойство PriceForHour следующим способом:

```
public partial class Student
     {
        public double PriceForHour
        {
            get { return this.Price / this.LessonLength; }
        }
    }
```

Свойства биндятся в датагрид в xaml следующим образом

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="studentsGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserResizeColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,0,81,0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Surname}" Header="Фамилия" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Имя"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClassNumber}" Header="Класс"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Street.Street_Name}" Header="Улица" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HouseNumber}" Header="Дом" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ApartmentNumber}" Header="Квартира" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PriceForHour}" Header="Цена в час" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

В .cs

```
        studentsGrid.ItemsSource = ((App)App.Current).currentTeacher.Students;
```

Отображается всё, кроме PriceForHour, в режиме отладки у студента видно, что поле заполнено корректно.
Что я делаю не так? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы вообще не должны привязываться к модели. База данных не имеет права бежать в UI-потоке.

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать название технологии или паттерна, по которому следует организовать работу с БД и биндингом? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну, по идее это MVVM.